# AngularJS Image onclick should show a List

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, user-experience

I am new to the angular dev. This is my first project I am doing on my own

I would like to create a page that shows images and on-clicking one of those images must show me a list of items below the image.

**Example is given in this link.** 
http://www.hbo.com/schedule/hbonow-hbogo?category=Series&cmpid=now_order_series&subCategory=PMRS48

I tried finding the solution in the internet and I did find few ones but not a clear idea of how to create one such example.

Comment: Please show whatever you have done and community will guide you accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h1 ng-click="showItem(item.id)">{item.title}</h1>
    <ul ng-show="item.showDetails">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $scope.showItem = function(itemId){
        $scope.items.map(function(item){
            if(item.id == itemId){
                item.showDetails = true;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```